# Is it possible to specify Emotions for specific lines of text in Google Text-To-Speech?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to create a Children's Animation / Short Story and put it on YouTube.
I'm hoping to use Google Translate and Text-To-Speech to generate different language versions.

Since I'll need voices to express different emotions, I was wondering whether there is a way to do the following:

1. Have different voices for boys/ girls/ grown-ups/ animals etc?
2. For each line, specify an emotion. e.g: angry/ sad/ excited etc.

Can Google's Text-To-Speech allow for this customization?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Text-To-Speech it is not possible to assign emotions to voices. Currently the only options for voices are adult male and female voices in different languages. See available voice list [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices). There are some voices in the list that are using the [WaveNet model](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/wavenet#wavenet_voices) which makes the voice sound like a real adult person.

The customization that Google's Text-To-Speech uses [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#support-for-ssml-elements) and is currently limited to providing details on pauses, and audio formatting for acronyms, dates, times, abbreviations, or text that should be censored.

I suggest to explore other Text-to-Speech providers to fit your use case.